# keyboard on ipad not showing up using phonegap and HTML5 input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, cordova

I generated an app using phonegap into an IPA file and loaded it on my IPAD3.  When I test my mobile app using a browser the keyboard function works great(mobile.koolantkoolers.com), but now in the native app it doesn't come up?  Do i need some sort of click event handler?  I thought this was all handled through the phonegap library?  Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Turned off Hydration mode and it corrected the problem thanks though!